# How to programmatically set folder permissions on win7?

Tags: windows-7, file-permissions

What is the preferred way, either by script or Windows API to set folder permissions on Windows7?

Answer (score 1):

The sample is for a file but the way to modify the access control list is the same.

How to add an access-allowed ACE to a file

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/102102